# Вставить данные в QML TablView

Tags: qt, qt5, qtcreator, qml

Имеется таблица, в которую нужно вставить данные из текстового файла:

```
TableView {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    sortIndicatorOrder: 0
    anchors.bottomMargin: 55

            TableViewColumn {
                role: "user_id"    // Эти роли совпадают с названиями ролей в C++ модели
                title: "User ID"
            }

            TableViewColumn {
                role: "username"    // Эти роли совпадают с названиями ролей в C++ модели
                title: "Username"
            }

            TableViewColumn {
                role: "phone_number"    // Эти роли совпадают с названиями ролей в C++ модели
                title: "Phone number"
            }
            // Устанавливаем модель в TableView
            model: myModel

            Button {
                x: 533
                y: 441
                text: "Задать путь!"
               //onClicked: main.main();
            }

            TextInput {
                x: 250
                y: 441
                width: 224
                height: 23
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
                font.family: "Arial"
                cursorVisible: true
            }

            Text {
                id: pathtxt
                x: 8
                y: 441
                width: 223
                height: 23
                text: "Введите путь до файла с расширением .txt: "
                textFormat: Text.AutoText
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
            }
```

Собственно не получается додумать алгоритм для вставки:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QString path;

    QFile file1(path);

    if(file1.exists())
    {
        QTextStream stream1(&file1);

        while(!stream1.atEnd())
        {
            QString line = stream1.readLine();

             QStringList standartStringList;

            for (QString item : line.split(";")) {
                 standartStringList.append(item);
        }

    }}

    QQuickView view;
    QQmlContext *ctxt = view.rootContext();
    ctxt->setContextProperty("myModel", standartStringList);

    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:main.qml"));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();}
```

P.S. выводит каждое слово в одну строку( то есть в userid, username, phonenumber выводится одно и тоже слово, когда нужно каждое слово по отдельности)

Comment: Откуда `dataList` взялся?

Comment: Alexander Chernin, отредактировал

Comment: Похоже вот ваш случай http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html

Comment: Да я уже был по данной ссылке. Пытаюсь самостоятельно дописать код, но не получается.